# How do I display a list that contains the number of individual letters in a list of names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of names and a list of the alphabet. I am able to determine the number of a single letter at a time. How do I check make python go through my entire alphabet list and append them in order.

```
listOfNames = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing",
               "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Lovelace", "Noether",
               "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]

alphaList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
alphaCount = []
letterCount = 0
for names in listOfNames:
    for letter in names:
        if letter.lower() in alphaList[0]:
            letterCount += 1
alphaCount.append(letterCount)
print(alphaCount)

Outcome == [9]
expected outcome == [9, 2,.....] #number of 'a's , number of 'b's...etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simpler code with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listOfNames = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing",
               "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Lovelace", "Noether",
               "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]

di = defaultdict(int)
for name in listOfNames:
    for letter in name:
        di[letter.lower()] += 1

print(dict(di))
```

Outputs:

```
{'e': 17, 'u': 4, 'c': 7, 'l': 7, 'i': 8, 'd': 3, 'a': 9, 'r': 7, 'h': 3, 'm': 2, 's': 8, 'n': 9, 'w': 2, 't': 8, 'o': 8, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'b': 2, 'v': 1, 'p': 1}
```

**EDITED:**

I won't say it is the most efficient solution but it works. To generate a list of alphabets, I have used `string.ascii_lowercase` in `string` module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import string

listOfNames = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing",
               "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Lovelace", "Noether",
               "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]

di = defaultdict(int)
for name in listOfNames:
    for letter in name:
        di[letter.lower()] += 1


alphaCount = [dict(di).get(i, 0) for i in list(string.ascii_lowercase)]
print(alphaCount)
```

Outputs:

```
[9, 2, 7, 3, 17, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: this is the outcome im looking for.   # [9, 2, 7, 3, 17, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]    9 'a's 2 'b's  3'a's. im a beginner so i dont understand much.

Comment: I am getting the same output as you desired with simpler code. Let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: nice. it has the right outcome but if i want to refer back to the listed outcome what variable will i use?

Comment: See my edited answer. I have stored the list in `li` variable. I am using `string.ascii_lowercase` to generate a list of alphabets. It is better method to do that.

Comment: in the original i have my values stored in alphacount.

Comment: Thank you so much. I dont completely understand what exactly is happening but i will study it.

Comment: Could you help me solve this but by using for or while loops. I want to understand what I am looking at better. I upvoted your answer too. It wont show publicly till i get more points!

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your code to instead produce a dictionary of counts for each letter

```
alphaCount = {}
for name in listOfNames:
    for letter in name:
        letter_lower = letter.lower()
        if letter_lower in alphaCount:
            alphaCount[letter_lower] += 1
        else:
            alphaCount[letter_lower] = 1
```

Result

```
>>> alphaCount
{'e': 17, 'u': 4, 'c': 7, 'l': 7, 'i': 8, 'd': 3, 'a': 9, 'r': 7, 'h': 3, 'm': 2, 's': 8, 'n': 9, 'w': 2, 't': 8, 'o': 8, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'b': 2, 'v': 1, 'p': 1}
```

If you want a list of counts in alphabetical order, you can use this dictionary in a list comprehension

```
>>> [alphaCount.get(i, 0) for i in alphaList]
[9, 2, 7, 3, 17, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasnt totally clear but i want the outcome to be the total number of a's, b's,c's,d's and so forth. so far my outcome is only the total number of a's in my list which is 9.

Comment: @FabianRosas See the edit at the bottom of my post for that solution.

Comment: Im a beginner so i dont know how to implement .get into my code.

Comment: is it an import?

Comment: Also worth mentioning you can use `collections.Counter`, `collections.defaultdict`, or `dict.setdefault` to simplify the code a bit. (Or you could `dict.fromkeys(alphaList, 0)`)

Comment: @FabianRosas `.get` is an attribute of any `dict` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
list_name=map(str.lower,listOfNames)
out=Counter(chain.from_iterable(list_name))
# Counter({'e': 17, 'a': 9, 'n': 9, 'i': 8, 's': 8, 't': 8, 'o': 8, 'c': 7, 'l': 7, 'r': 7, 'u': 4, 'd': 3, 'h': 3, 'm': 2, 'w': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'b': 2, 'v': 1, 'p': 1})
```

To get in alphabetical order of counts

```
[out[k] for k in alphaList]
# [9, 2, 7, 3, 17, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I see you got the outcome but i still dont know how i would write the code. to implement [out[k] for k in alphaList]

Answer (score 0):

a combination of `join` and `Counter` would be a good solution

```
listOfNames = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing",
               "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Lovelace", "Noether",
               "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]

r = "".join(listOfNames).lower()

from collections import Counter

sol = Counter(r)
print(sol)
```

output

```
Counter({'e': 17, 'a': 9, 'n': 9, 'i': 8, 's': 8, 't': 8, 'o': 8, 'c': 7, 'l': 7, 'r': 7, 'u': 4, 'd': 3, 'h': 3, 'm': 2, 'w': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'b': 2, 'v': 1, 'p': 1})
```

way 2 using `while`

```
# your code goes here

listOfNames = ["Euclid", "Archimedes", "Newton", "Descartes", "Fermat", "Turing",
               "Euler", "Einstein", "Boole", "Fibonacci", "Lovelace", "Noether",
               "Nash", "Wiles", "Cantor", "Gauss", "Plato"]
length = len(listOfNames)
count = 0

solution = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0,
'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 
'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0,
'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 
'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}

while count<length:
    for character in listOfNames[count]:
        solution[character.lower()]+=1
    count+=1


print(solution)
```

output

```
{'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 3, 'e': 17, 
 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 3, 'i': 8, 'j': 0,
 'k': 0, 'l': 7, 'm': 2, 'n': 9, 'o': 8,
 'p': 1, 'q': 0, 'r': 7, 's': 8, 't': 8, 
 'u': 4, 'v': 1, 'w': 2, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 
 'z': 0}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution but I want to do it with simple for loops and while loops. I just started coding so I wanted a solution similiar to my first post. Do you know of an implementation for a while loop and get the solution. # [9, 2, 7, 3, 17, 2, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 2, 9, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 8, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0] there are 9 'a's, 2 'b's and so forth